# TypeError: object has nonetype' len() and stops iteration

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm trying to run the following code but it prints error after "right side: None",
when it is suppose to say "right side: [2,4]"

```
data =  [9,5,7,4,2,8,1,10,6,3]

def mergeSort(list):
    if len(list) < 2:
        return list
    
    middle = len(list)//2 
    
    #Break the list in 2 pieces
    left = mergeSort(list[:middle])
    right = mergeSort(list[middle:])
    
    print("Left side: ", left)
    print("Right side: ", right)
    
    
    merged = merge(left, right)
    print("Merged", merged)
    return merged
    
def merge(left,right):

    if not len(left):
        return left
    if not len(right):
        return right 

    result = []
    leftIndex = 0
    rightIndex = 0 
    totalLen = len(left) + len(right)


    while (len(result) < totalLen):
        if left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex]:
            result.append(left[leftIndex])
            leftIndex+= 1
        else: 
            result.append(right[rightIndex])
            rightIndex+= 1 
      
        if leftIndex == len(left) or \
            rightIndex == len(right):
                result.extend(left[leftIndex:]
                             or right[rightIndex:])
                break
        return result
        
mergeSort(data)
```

the code works for the first couple of iterations but stops and gives error type: 'NoneType' has no len().

### Traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-50291ed7231f> in <module>
     47         return result
     48 
---> 49 mergeSort(data)

<ipython-input-66-50291ed7231f> in mergeSort(list)
      8 
      9     #Break the list in 2 pieces
---> 10     left = mergeSort(list[:middle])
     11     right = mergeSort(list[middle:])
     12 

<ipython-input-66-50291ed7231f> in mergeSort(list)
      9     #Break the list in 2 pieces
     10     left = mergeSort(list[:middle])
---> 11     right = mergeSort(list[middle:])
     12 
     13     print("Left side: ", left)

<ipython-input-66-50291ed7231f> in mergeSort(list)
     15 
     16 
---> 17     merged = merge(left, right)
     18     print("Merged", merged)
     19     return merged

<ipython-input-66-50291ed7231f> in merge(left, right)
     23     if not len(left):
     24         return left
---> 25     if not len(right):
     26         return right
     27 

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: If you execute the `break` statement in `merge()`, it never executes `return result`, so `merge()` returns `None` by default. Maybe `return result` should not be in the `while` loop?

Comment: The current error is cause in `if not len(left)` and `if not len(right)`. Change them to `if not left` and `if not right`, respectively. Those catch if `left` or `right` is an empty list.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thank you. I tried de indenting the 'return result' outside of the loop and it worked.!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your merge function to this

```
def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    for elem in left:
        if elem < right[0]:
            result.append(elem)
        else:
            result.append(right.pop(0))
    return result + right
```

Comment: If my memory is correct, this will be slow if the list is large: `right.pop(0)`. Python lists are not well optimized for left-side pops: it requires data copying. I think the `deque` module was written partly with this use case in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have some diagnostic printing in `mergeSort()`, but the problems are in `merge()`.

```
    if not len(left):
        return left                # Should be right.
    if not len(right):
        return right               # Should be left.

    while (len(result) < totalLen):
        if ...
            ...
        else ...
            ...
        if ...
            ...
            break
        return result              # Should be outside the while loop.
```